# Advice on handling networking opportunity professionally

Tags: professionalism, career-development, networking

Some background:

A year ago, I got laid off from a non-programming type of job. They were putting me through graduate school for Computer Engineering, and got my MS. I programmed a fair amount in school, but not enough to put it down as professional experience (I just took classes, no thesis).

So I got a new job. I did not feel interested in the work, but had to get it to get a paycheck. In the meantime, I got an opportunity to work in a new job with slightly higher pay (8k), so I made the jump. I have been in my current position for 5 months now and am very happy.

Last weekend, I went on a ski trip with a group of people I did not know very well. One of them was a technology director for a digital media company. She said that she had some opportunities available, but I declined because frankly, I didn't know if it would look good job hopping so much, and do not want to deal with the stress of hopping again. I got her information and emailed her saying I will keep in touch and that I am glad we met.

I am thinking I may have made a mistake, and want to ask her if she had any openings available and if I would be interested in them. I am only a year into professional programming, and if the pay wasn't drastically higher (like 20%) I probably wouldn't make the move. Is this professional? Would she see me as indecisive if I tried to reconsider? If not, how should I go about asking her about the opportunities she has?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tell her like it is, that you've decided you'd be interested in hearing about any opportunities she has after all.  I don't see how this will negatively affect you.  Perhaps she'll turn you down, but then you won't be any worse off than you already are.  If she does end up thinking less of you for changing your mind, it's something so minor, she's not going to run around telling everyone else that, and that's really the important detail.

Comment: All good points. I sent her the message. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid telling anyone you're not interested in any opportunities.  Just don't lead them to think you're ready to jump ship tomorrow.

You can simply say, "I'm pretty happy where I am, but if the right opportunity came along, I would always be interested in talking about it."

Honest, but non-confrontational and leaves the door open for them to approach you in the future.